# How could be calculated a PSU for 5 large sata discs enclosure?

Tags: power-supply

I have a Lycom UB-208RM USB3.0 & eSATA to 5 Driver H/W RAID Adapter and 5 WD Blue 6TB 5400 RPM, SATA 6 Gb/s, 64 MB Cache, 3.5" - WD60EZRZ. What is the specification of a PSU to power them properly?

Upadate: davidgo is right. I have searched more and found this: [How to prevent disk i/o timeouts which cause disks to disconnect and data corruption with SMR disks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541463/how-to-prevent-disk-i-o-timeouts-which-cause-disks-to-disconnect-and-data-corrup) I've used that solution and it works fine. Now, I need only a persisted solution.

Comment: The drives each require 1.75 amps @12 volts (give or take 10%) peak, + overhead for equipment as per https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-blue-hdd/data-sheet-wd-blue-pc-hard-drives-2879-771436.pdf so you will want a PSU that is rated at 12 volts, 120 watts or more (specifically something able to put out 10 amps or more in the 12 volt line). This excludes any power for any devices other then the aforementioned.  (I've commented not answered as I've not used this gear and padded the numbers a wee bit)

Comment: I have a FSP300-60GHS 300W 85+, but it seems something is wrong, I can't find the reason yet. The setup worked fine for 2TB or 3TB drives, but it seems that 6TB discs challenge something. They seem to disconnect after a while during data transfer, but they work fine in a regular PC.

Comment: Maybe its not power related. Hypothesizong way beyond the bounds of my knowledge here - it may be that the drives are occasionally taking to long on a read and timing out. The specs don't mention they are RAID capable, and this behaviour is a key difference between drive types (ie the drives may not like the controller) Google tler (time limited error recovery)

Comment: The Lycom UB-208RM is a discontinued product and it only supports SATA II (3 Gbps). The drives that you upgraded to are SATA 6 Gb/s. They should still work, but **since the Lycom UB-208RM is discontinued, it has not been tested with new drives.** Were the 3TB drives you had before SATA III (6 Gbps) as well, or were they SATA II (3 Gbps)?

Comment: I don't use RAID. All drives were SATA III. I've used it with 2 x 6TB drives along 2 TB or 3TB others, it worked, but as I have all 6TB now, seems something is overloaded.

Comment: The test I've done is to copy 1.2TB on one of the discs, the discs being not mounted in the OS (I use Linux), except for the one I copy to. After e while, but that is not linear, I mean it faild after 200GB or after 50GB, it becomes unaccessible. It is interesting, it can't become available even the enclosure is turned off, but if I restart the OS it becomes available again. The copy error is 30 (in KDE/Dolphin), but I can't find the meaning. I have copied on it already a large amount, if I read that back, it also kind of "ejects". I'll test with other discs now.

Comment: Interestingly, one drive is having this behavior. But in this setup only, not in the regular PC. How would I know it is defective or it simply can't work in this setup only?

Comment: @davidgo, I think you are right, according to the kernel logs, I see there are timeouts sometimes, for the  large drives (of 6TB). I guess they need more time to do some operations in some cases.